# program that writes the even and odd numbers

Tags: c

I was writting a program that can read a set of numbers file called dog.txt;
and also writes to two file separating odd and even. i was able to compile my program however, the output expected is not the same which was supposed to be even numbers in one file called EVEN, odd numbers in file odd.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int i;
  int even,odd;
  int num;

  if (argc != 4) {
    printf("Usage: executable in_file  output_file\n");
    exit(0);
  }

  FILE *dog = fopen(argv[1], "r");
  FILE *feven= fopen(argv[2], "w");
  FILE *fodd= fopen (argv[3], "w");
  while (fscanf(dog, "%d", &num) != EOF)
    {
      if (0==i%2){
        i++;
         printf("even= %d\n", num);
         }
      else if(i!=0){
       i++;
       printf("odd= %d\n", num);
      }
    }
  fclose(feven);
  fclose(fodd);
  fclose(dog);

  return 0;
}
```

output:

```
even= 1
odd= 2
even= 34
odd= 44
even= 66
odd= 78
even= 94
odd= 21
even= 23
odd= 54
even= 44
odd= 65
even= 78
odd= 68
even= 92
```

Comment: Is this a homework assignment? :)

Comment: Homework by any chance? In this case you should learn how the loops and the file I/O works first; This example just demonstrates you get it very wrong.

Comment: No way, this is clearly an enterprise application.

Comment: BTW, you don't open a file called dog.txt, EVEN and ODD. Your files are named according to the command line parameters. The name of the variable holding a file pointer (FILE*) has nothing to do with file name.

Answer (score 4):

You're checking `i % 2`, not `num % 2`. I'm not even sure what `i` does in this example—perhaps you're planning on using it later.

```
while (fscanf(dog, "%d", &num) != EOF) {
    if (num % 2 == 0) {
        printf("even = %d\n", num);
    }
    else if(num != 0) {
        printf("odd = %d\n", num);
    }
}
```

I imagine the code to write these numbers to the files will come later, once you've fixed this bug.

Comment: `i` isn't even initialized properly.

Answer (score 0):

The code contains no instructions to write into the output files.  It only writes to stdout.

Answer (score 0):

The `printf` function writes to the screen (more correctly, it writes to "standard output", but that is usually the screen). You want to write to a file. You have opened files called `feven` and `fodd`. To write to them, you would use the `fprintf` call, which works like `printf` except it takes an extra (left-most) argument, which is the `FILE*` that you want to write to, e.g.

```
FILE *fmyfile = fopen("myfile.txt", "w");
fprintf(fmyfile, "The magic number is %d!", 3);
```

Also, your results are incorrect, but that's an unrelated problem.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the `printf`/`fprintf` problem, in any decent modern compiler, that code should be generating a warning that you're not assigning any initial value to `i`.

Comment: Uninitialized variables are not a compile-time error in C or C++, they just have an arbitrary value (whatever used to be in the memory that they're using) until you do initialize them. A good compiler should warn, though.

Comment: @Tyler: Quite true, good point. Heck, the compilers I was using *twenty years ago* included those sorts of lint features. I suppose it should *compile*, just with warnings. But still, ignore warnings at your peril. :-)